# Google Extension to Fix Webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension to fix a webpage. I don't have access to change the webpage or I would.

The HTML elements that are breaking the page don't have IDs, but NAMEs. However, looking at the javascript, it's doing a multiple document.getElementById() calls using NAMEs. This works fine in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox.

My idea is to write a Chrome Extension to insert the needed element IDs. Is this possible?

**background.js:**

```
var dateChange = document.getElementsByName('DateChange');
dateChange.id = 'DateChange';
```

**mainpage.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function do_stuff()
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById('DateChange');
        // do some more stuff
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="DateChange" value="false" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use attribute selectors such as

```
input[name="DateChange"] { color: red }
```

Also see the relatively new `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` calls.

Comment: But can attribute selectors change an element's ID?

    input[name="DateChange"] { id: "myId" }

Comment: No. You can however select the element with `querySelector` and use JS to add the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I must have been doing something wrong before when trying to set the IDs. However, I have found the following to work for my purposes:

```
var myForm = document.getElementsByName('myForm')[0];
var elLength = myForm.length;
for (i=0; i<elLength; i++)
{
    myForm.elements[i].id = myForm.elements[i].name;
}
```